# Javascript IF statement with null condition error

Tags: javascript, null, conditional-statements

In the following IF statement, one of the conditions is sometimes null.

Parse.User.current() can be null, in which case I'll get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
```

Is there an elegant way to avoid this error?

```
if( post.get("parent").id != Parse.User.current().id ) {

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cleaner way can be :

```
var current = Parse.User.current();

if(current && post.get("parent").id !== current.id ) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then check like this

```
if(Parse.User.current() !== null)
{
if( post.get("parent").id !== Parse.User.current().id ) {
//Do whatever necessary
}
}
```